# Chrome extension: receive message in injected script not working

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

Simplified version of my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "description",
    "icons":
    {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "32": "icon32.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "browser_action":
    {},
    "background":
    {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs", "downloads", "<all_urls>", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["background.css"]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab)
{
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS({
        file: "sai.css"
    }, function()
    {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "sai.js"});
    });
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "sendurls.js", allFrames: true});
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(urls)
    {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(urls);
    });
});
```

**sendurls.js**

```
var sai =
{
    urls: []
};

console.log("Injected by sendurls.js");
sai.urls = [].slice.apply(document.links).map(function(e){return e.href;});
console.log("Result: ", sai.urls);
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(sai.urls);
```

**sai.css**

```
#headerdiv
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    z-index: 999999999999;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

**sai.js**

```
var sai =
{
    headerdiv: document.createElement("div"),
    urls: []
}

function closeheaderdiv()
{
    document.body.removeChild(headerdiv);
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(urls)
{
    var newurl;
    for (var idx in urls)
    {
        newurl = urls[idx];
        newurl.index = sai.urls.length;
        sai.urls.push(newurl);
    }
    alert(sai.urls[0].url);
});

sai.headerdiv.id = "headerdiv";
sai.headerdiv.innerHTML = "overlay div";
sai.headerdiv.onclick = closeheaderdiv;
document.body.appendChild(sai.headerdiv);
```

What I have here is a basic Chrome extension that gets the links in the document in `sendurls.js` and attempts to send them to `sai.js` using `background.js` as an intermediary. I'm only using `background.js` as an intermediary because sending the message directly from `sendurls.js` to `sai.js` fails, plus, only in `background.js` I can use `chrome.tabs`, as far as I know (since I don't have a popup). I intentionally didn't make a popup for this attempt, since I want to display some *potentially* "dangerous" iframes in `sai.js` (this is what I was supposed to have in the popup) and I need the additional security of extensions like UBlock Origin or UMatrix, which, as far as I know, don't check/block the popup (but do check/block a "normal" page with iframes and an injected script, aka target page + `sai.js`). Basically, I trigger the execution by clicking the extension icon (i.e. `background.js`'s `onClicked` listener), expecting for the links to be sent to `sai.js` from `sendurls.js`; then I attempt to manipulate the page's DOM by drawing an "overlay div" over the page, where I will put some buttons and, in a 2nd div at the bottom of the page, display the iframes I talked about above.

The problem I have is that `sai.js` doesn't seem to get the message with the urls that is sent by either `background.js` or `sendurls.js`, and I don't know what I can do to correct it. I was using largely the same setup when I had a popup (e.g. receiving the urls from `sendurls.js` in the popup, then sending them to an injected script pretty much like `sai.js`, by executing it) and it worked like a charm, but now that I use only `background.js` it doesn't (I'm not executing `sai.js` anymore when sending the message, as I would like to run it only once - since manipulating the DOM the same way repeatedly is kind of redundant and ineffective).

What should I do to achieve what I want (get the urls from `sendurls.js` to `sai.js`)?

Comment: To send a message to a content script you should have used chrome.tabs.sendMessage with tab id as the first parameter. Also, to prevent race conditions, injection of sendurls script should be moved into a callback of sai's executeScript

Comment: Tab id, as far as I know, 'defaults to the active tab of the current window' if not specified, as per [Chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript), so I see no problem there. On chrome.tabs.sendMessage and the injection of sendurls script in the callback of sai's executeScript, feel free to edit it accordingly, if it solves the problem. I just want the issue working, that's all.

Comment: You need chrome.tabs.sendMessage instead of chrome.runtime.sendMessage to send a message from the background script to the content script. It's a different function with different syntax for different purpose. This is as far as I'm willing to contribute here. If my comment is not helpful, wait for someone to provide a complete answer.

Comment: I looked into it a few moments ago, you are correct. I now get the alert from sai.js (which means the thing is moving in the right direction), but it says undefined (it should be the first url). EDIT: when I changed `sai.urls[0].url` to `sai.urls` I did get the url array though, so it might need some tweaking. It seems to be working, at last, thank you very much - don't be upset about my reply, I am now at the point of being bothered to even think too much, as I spent quite some time "debugging" this to no avail. I got the current tab id using that long `chrome.tabs.query` thing, is it ok?